# Setting UIButton Image Using AFNetworking

Tags: objective-c, tags, uibutton, uiimage, afnetworking

I have this code in my project that creates UIButtons with labels and images with values coming from a web service.

```
- (void)getMoviePosterImages
{
    for (int i = 0; i < [self.rowCount intValue]; i++)
    {
        NSArray *postersArray = [self.jsonMutableArray objectAtIndex:i];
        AFImageRequestOperation *operation  = [AFImageRequestOperation imageRequestOperationWithRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[postersArray objectAtIndex:6]]] imageProcessingBlock:nil
        success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image)
        {
            [moviePosterButton setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
        failure:nil];

        [operation start];
    }
}
```

Here's the code where I created the UILabels:

```
- (void)displayMovieTitlesAndFrames
{
    int imageCount = [self.rowCount intValue];
    int offset_x = 21;
    int offset_y = 24;

    for (int i = 0; i < imageCount; i++)
    {
        // compute x & y offset
        if (i % 3 == 0)
        {
            offset_x = 21;
        }
        else if (i % 3 == 1)
        {
            offset_x = 115;
        }
        else
        {
            offset_x = 210;
        }

        whiteBackgroundLabel = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(offset_x, offset_y, MOVIE_THUMBNAIL_W, MOVIE_THUMBNAIL_H)] autorelease];
        whiteBackgroundLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        whiteBackgroundLabel.layer.cornerRadius = 3.0;
        whiteBackgroundLabel.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor lightGrayColor] CGColor];
        whiteBackgroundLabel.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
        [scrollview addSubview:whiteBackgroundLabel];

        moviePosterButton = [[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom] retain];
        moviePosterButton.frame = CGRectMake(offset_x + 5, offset_y + 5, MOVIE_THUMBNAIL_W - 10, MOVIE_THUMBNAIL_H - 10);
        moviePosterButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        [moviePosterButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        moviePosterButton.tag = i;
        [moviePosterButton addTarget:self
                              action:@selector(imageButtonPressed:)
                    forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [scrollview addSubview:moviePosterButton];

        movieTitleLabel = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(offset_x, offset_y + 143, 90, 20)] autorelease];
        movieTitleLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        movieTitleLabel.layer.cornerRadius = 3.0;
        movieTitleLabel.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor lightGrayColor] CGColor];
        movieTitleLabel.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
        movieTitleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:11.0];
        movieTitleLabel.textColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
        movieTitleLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
        movieTitleLabel.numberOfLines = 1;
        movieTitleLabel.text = [[self.jsonMutableArray objectAtIndex:i] objectAtIndex:1];
        [scrollview addSubview:movieTitleLabel];

        quickBuyButton = [[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom] retain];
        quickBuyButton.frame = CGRectMake(offset_x + 1 + (MOVIE_THUMBNAIL_W - QUICK_BUY_BUTTON_W - 2), offset_y - 1 + 2, QUICK_BUY_BUTTON_W, QUICK_BUY_BUTTON_H);
        quickBuyButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        [quickBuyButton setBackgroundImage:QUICK_BUY_BUTTON forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        quickBuyButton.tag = i;
        [quickBuyButton addTarget:self
                           action:@selector(quickBuyButtonPressed:)
                 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [scrollview addSubview:quickBuyButton];

        // increment offset
        if (offset_x == 210)
        {
            offset_y += 171;
        }
    }

    if ((offset_x == 21) || (offset_x == 115))
    {
        offset_y += 171;
    }

    [self adjustScrollViewAndBackground:offset_y];
}
```

All my UIButtons are created with their respective tags and I want to put their images on each on those buttons. The code above works only on the last UIButton created. I want to populate all of my buttons with images using the code above. Can someone tell me where I'm getting it all wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In your `getMoviePosterImages` method you are setting an image to the `moviePosterButton` which might be the last button you just created so this is normal if only the last button gets  its image. You need either to retrieve each buttons by their tags or build an array with all you buttons so you can easily access them. You could maybe do something like that:

```
- (void)getMoviePosterImages
{
    for (int i = 0; i < [self.rowCount intValue]; i++)
    {
        NSArray *postersArray = [self.jsonMutableArray objectAtIndex:i];
        AFImageRequestOperation *operation  = [AFImageRequestOperation imageRequestOperationWithRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[postersArray objectAtIndex:6]]] imageProcessingBlock:nil
        success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image)
        {
            [(UIButton *)buttonsArray[i] setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            // or
            // [(UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:i] setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
        failure:nil];

        [operation start];
    }
}
```

Hope this helps ;)

Comment: my buttons are inside a scrollview. How can I implement it? `self.scrollView` doesn't work.

Comment: just use `scrollview`. I've also noticed that moviePosterButton.tag and quickBuyButton.tag have the same tag, this is not good

Comment: That's ok. quickBuyButton is just a generic image.